# Problems with paintComponent and mouseListener

Tags: java, paintcomponent, mouselistener

I'm trying to mark a triangle (that I've marked out on a picture) with a rectangle on a picture. I've managed to paint the triangle but I can't mark it with the rectangle.
Here's the code I've written so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

abstract class Places extends JComponent {

    private boolean marked;

    private String placeName;
    private PlacePosition position;
    private String placeColor;
    private String placeCategory;

    public Places(String name, String category, PlacePosition position) {

        setBounds(position.x, position.y, 20, 20);

        placeName = name;
        this.position = position;
        placeCategory = category;
        this.placeColor = placeColor;

        mouseListener mL = new mouseListener();
    }

    public Color rightColor() {
        Color c = Color.BLACK;
        switch (placeCategory) {
        case "None":
          c = Color.BLACK;
          break;
        case "Buss":
            c = Color.RED;
            break;
        case "Tunnelbana":
            c = Color.BLUE;
            break;
        case "Tåg":
            c = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        }
        return c;
    }


    public PlacePosition getPosition() {
        return position;
        }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int[] polyX = { 0, 15, 30 };
        int[] polyY = { 0, 30, 0 };

        setBounds(position.x - 15, position.y - 30, 30, 30);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        g.setColor(rightColor());
        g.fillPolygon(polyX, polyY, 3);

        if (marked) {
            g.drawRect(30, 30, 30, 30);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    abstract void printText();

    class mouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mE) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(mE)) {
                if (!marked) {
                marked = true;
                } else {
                    marked = false;
                }
            }

            revalidate();
            repaint();
       }
    }
}
```

My guess is that there's something that doesn't work with the mouseListener, but I'm quite uncertain. Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You never add a MouseListener to anything, so your MouseAdapter class will have no effect. For any listener to work, you must first add the listener to the listened-to component. So figure out what you want to add the listener to, and then call `addMouseListener(...)` on that component.

A side recommendation: **never** call `repaint()` from within a paintComponent method or any other painting method.

Comment: Omg, this was an annoying miss... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why shouldn't you call a repaint() from within a paintComponent method?

Comment: @MyJärphed: You're essentially creating a "poor man's game loop", one that you have absolutely no control over, and one that changes in a fundamental way the actions of a key Swing method. The paintComponent method is for painting and only painting and should never be used for a bastardized game loop. Use a Swing Timer or some other construct that you'll have more control over.